# iterating a Qml across multiple screens

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

It shows qml on main screen. I want to repeat the same image on other screens. They will all be exactly the same. It will be renewed on all screens according to the change in Main. Is something like this possible ?

code in main.qml

```
PlaybackControl {
    id: playbackControl
    anchors {
        right: parent.right
        left: parent.left
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }
    mediaPlayer: mediaPlayer
    mediaPlayer2: mediaPlayer2
}
```

**Edit:**
I want to run a qml to run concurrently on each window. I added new images. state1 main screen. There are 6 windows on the main screen. When I drag one of the screens out. I want the control bar below to appear on the screen that comes out. It will appear at the bottom of every screen that is removed. When I change the slider on one screen, it will change simultaneously on all screens. When I make the control bar a component and use it as an initial item in more than one stackview, it shows the last inial item I called without duplicating the source.

[image: state1]
[image: state2]

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean. Possible what? In general a `Window` has [Window.screen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-window.html#screen-prop) property to specify the screen. The all available screens list is available as [Application.screens](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-application.html#screens-prop).

Comment: @folibis I want to call PlaybackControl on multiple screens simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, loop through the `screens` array and create the same window on  each screen.

Comment: @folibis Do you know any examples for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is some simple test application that should dynamically create and show the same window on each available screen in its top-right corner

```js
ApplicationWindow {
    id: main
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Multiple screens test")

    property list<Window> windows;

    Component {
        id: windowComponent
        Window {
            id: window
            width: 200
            height: 50
            visible: true
            flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
            property alias caption: txt.text
            x: screen.width - window.width
            y: 0
            Text {
                id: txt
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: ""
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var screens = Application.screens;
        for(var s in screens)
        {
            var wnd = windowComponent.createObject(main.contentItem, { screen: screens[s], caption: "some text" });
            main.windows.push(wnd);
            wnd.show();
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "change caption"
        onClicked: {
            for(var w in main.windows) {
                main.windows[w].caption = "another text";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The each window is stored in an array so you can access that.

Comment: not actually accessing a variable in another window. I updated the post in detail with the images.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I have seen is:

1. `StackView` control used for `Page` navigation
2. The application declares a `footer` that is seen on all pages
3. Each page declares a unique `header`

The impact of this is that every page will see the same `footer` but a different `header`. I implement a media `play` and `stop` `Button` in the footer. The header shows which page you are on and there is inter-page navigation.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    property bool started: false

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "MainPage.qml"
    }
    footer: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            AppIconButton {
                icon.source: started ? "square-32.svg" : "play-32.svg"
                onClicked: started = !started
            }
        }
    }
}

//MainPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    header: Frame {
        Text { text: "MainPage.qml" }
    }
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Second Page")
        onClicked: stackView.push("SecondPage.qml")
    }
}

//SecondPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    header: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            AppIconButton {
                icon.source: "chevron-left-32.svg"
                onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
            Text { text: "SecondPage.qml"
 }
        }
    }
}

//AppIconButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    id: iconButton
    Layout.preferredWidth: 32
    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
    property alias icon: btn.icon
    clip: true
    signal clicked()
    Button {
       id: btn
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       icon.width: parent.width
       icon.height: parent.icon
       onClicked: iconButton.clicked()
    }
}

//play-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M8 3.045v25.91l19-12.952zm1 1.893l16.225 11.064L9 27.062z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

//square-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M5.8 29h21.4a1.8 1.8 0 0 0 1.8-1.8V5.798A1.802 1.802 0 0 0 27.198 4h-21.4A1.8 1.8 0 0 0 4 5.798V27.2A1.8 1.8 0 0 0 5.8 29zM5 5.798A.798.798 0 0 1 5.798 5h21.4a.801.801 0 0 1 .802.798V27.2a.801.801 0 0 1-.8.8H5.8a.8.8 0 0 1-.8-.8z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

//chevron-left-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M18.793 25l-9-9 9-9h1.414l-9 9 9 9z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have one problem. If all the data is in a single window and only the qmls in it change, the solution you shared will be enough for me. But I have each qml in a different window, so I need to call a variable in main.qml separately from both the window and capture the same image in all of them.